# Как сделать, чтобы шар отскакивал от края под правильным углом?

Tags: javascript, математика

Не могу понять, какую формулу использовать, чтобы шар отскакивал под правильным углом.

```js
var ballRadius = 20;
var Width = 1200;
var Height = 600;
var PI = Math.PI;

var KEY
var x2, y2
var r = PI/2
var ran =  Math.floor(Math.random())
var player1 = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  width: 25,
  height: 150,
  update: function() {
    if (38 in KEY) {
        if(this.y > 0){
         this.y -= 17
        } 
        }
    
     else if (40 in KEY && this.y < canvas.height - this.height) {
      this.y += 17
    }
  },
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  },
  clear: function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  }
}
var player2 = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  width: 25,
  height: 150,
  update: function() {

  },

  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  },
   clear: function() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
}
var ball = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  speed: 5,
  velocity: null,
angle: null,
newAngle: null,
  update: function() {
   this.y = this.y +Math.cos(this.angle) * this.speed;
   this.x = this.x + Math.sin(this.angle) * this.speed;
if (this.y < 0 + ballRadius + PI){
  ball.angle =   180 - (this.newAngle/2)

 }

  },
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
  },
   clear: function() {
   ctx.beginPath();  
   ctx.clearRect(this.x - ballRadius - 1, this.y - ballRadius - 1, ballRadius * 2 + 2, ballRadius * 2 + 2);
   ctx.closePath();  }
}

function main() {

  canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  canvas.width = Width;
  canvas.height = Height;
  KEY = {

  }
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(even) {
    KEY[even.keyCode] = true
  }, false)
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(even) {
    delete KEY[even.keyCode];
  }, false)
  initial()
  var loop = function() {
    clear();
    update();
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas)
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas)
}

function initial() {
  player1.x = player1.width;
  player1.y = (canvas.height - player1.height) / 2;
  player2.x = canvas.width - (player1.width + player2.width);
  player2.y = (canvas.height - player2.height) / 2;
  ball.x = (canvas.width - ballRadius) / 2
  ball.y = (canvas.height - ballRadius) / 2
ball.angle = Math.floor((Math.random()*(90) + 45) * (180 + ran))
ball.velocity =  ball.speed/2
ball.newAngle = ball.angle
}

function update() {
  ball.update()
  player1.update()
  player2.update()


}
function newAngle(){
 
}
function draw() {

  ball.draw()
  player1.draw()
  player2.draw()
 
}

function clear() {

  player1.clear()
  player2.clear()
  ball.clear()

}
main()
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AeroHockey</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MenuScreen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PlayScreen.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```